# Facade bean not finding the correct rows when used on a MySQL view

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, netbeans-7

I have the following problem that is baffling me:

1) I have a MySQL view, that is getting info from different, related tables. If i run a plain select query on this, i get all the rows that i need.

```
userID          functionID      functionName    parentFunction  functionType    branchCode  
jg1             234561          Another Test    XXXXXX          T               001 
jg1             123456          Test Function   XXXXXX          T               001 
jg1             123457          Tendai          234561          T               001 
jg1             123458          Rutendo         234561          T               001 
jg1             XXXXXX          Root                                            001
```

2) I have created an entity based on this view as follows:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 35)
@Column(name = "userID")
@Id
private String userID;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 8)
@Column(name = "functionID")
private String functionID;
@Size(max = 35)
@Column(name = "functionName")
private String functionName;
@Size(max = 8)
@Column(name = "parentFunction")
private String parentFunction;
@Column(name = "functionType")
private Character functionType;
@Size(max = 3)
@Column(name = "branchCode")
private String branchCode;

....
....
public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getFunctionID() {
    return functionID;
}

public void setFunctionID(String functionID) {
    this.functionID = functionID;
}

public String getFunctionName() {
    return functionName;
}

public void setFunctionName(String functionName) {
    this.functionName = functionName;
}

public String getParentFunction() {
    return parentFunction;
}

public void setParentFunction(String parentFunction) {
    this.parentFunction = parentFunction;
}

public Character getFunctionType() {
    return functionType;
}

public void setFunctionType(Character functionType) {
    this.functionType = functionType;
}

public String getBranchCode() {
    return branchCode;
}

public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
}
```

....
...

3) I also have a facade bean created with a method to find all rows in the table. My problem is that the rows being returned by the find method just contain the details of one record, repeated over the number of records in the view.

```
List browserDetails = new ArrayList(40);
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("...findAll");
List rs = query.getResultList();
```

4) These are the results after using this facade bean in a jsf page...straight forward Netbeans wizard work

```
UserID  FunctionID  FunctionName    ParentFunction  FunctionType    BranchCode   
jg1     234561       Another Test   XXXXXX  T   001     View Edit Destroy
jg1     234561       Another Test   XXXXXX  T   001     View Edit Destroy
jg1     234561       Another Test   XXXXXX  T   001     View Edit Destroy
jg1     234561       Another Test   XXXXXX  T   001     View Edit Destroy
jg1     234561       Another Test   XXXXXX  T   001     View Edit Destroy`
```

I am not sure why this is only happening when i use the view, but i am able to get the right results when i use a table instead.